# Router is not defined

Tags: react-router

I had this code:

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'

render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <Route path="page1" component={ Page1 }/>
      <Route path="page2" component={ Page2 }/>
      <Route path="page3" component={ Page3 }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

And after compiling it with webpack and babeljs Google Chrome shows errors:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

As I figured the reason for that is Router is not exported as a property of 'react-router' and therefore Router component is 'undefined'

I use react-router version 0.13.5. What is the way to use it correctly?

Comment: I tried react-router version ^1.0.0-rc1 and now the same code is working just fine. But I'm still confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a change to the API of React Router between v0.13.x and the v1.0.0 pre-releases. It's just that the code you have works with e.g. the 1.0.0-rc1 API, but not with the different v0.13.x API.